# how to print a file to a specific printer in android using kotlin?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

Im working right now on an android application with kotlin and i want to print a pdf file with a specific printer in my network. Its the third day searching but i found nothing, i found that there's a library named android.printService and it can be used to print files but it provides a preview of the file and the user has to choose the printer he wants to use and click on the print button to print the file but in my application i want to send directly the file to the printer i choose so the user has not to do it. I also found that in java we can use a library javax.print to search printer in network using printservicelookup but in android i didn't find a way to do it and i didn't understand how to properly use the android.printservice even after reading the documentation about it, thank you for your help.

i used th efunction below to try to print but as i said it provides a review and the user has to choose himself a printer but i want to bypass that  and im not sure if i have to use a PrintDocumentAdapter to do it

```
class PrintServe : PrintService() {
    override fun onCreatePrinterDiscoverySession(): PrinterDiscoverySession {
        Log.d("myprinter", "MyPrintService#onCreatePrinterDiscoverySession() called")
        return object : PrinterDiscoverySession() {
            override fun onStartPrinterDiscovery(priorityList: List<PrinterId>) {
                Log.d(
                    "myprinter",
                    "PrinterDiscoverySession#onStartPrinterDiscovery(priorityList: $priorityList) called"
                )
                if (priorityList.isNotEmpty()) { return }

                val printers: MutableList<PrinterInfo> = ArrayList()
                val printerId = generatePrinterId("aaa")
                val builder = PrinterInfo.Builder(printerId, "dummy printer", PrinterInfo.STATUS_IDLE)
                val capBuilder = PrinterCapabilitiesInfo.Builder(printerId)
                capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4, true)
                capBuilder.addMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A3, false)

                capBuilder.addResolution(
                    Resolution("resolutionId", "default resolution", 600, 600),
                    true
                )

                capBuilder.setColorModes(
                    PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR or PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME,
                    PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR
                )
                builder.setCapabilities(capBuilder.build())
                printers.add(builder.build())


                addPrinters(printers)
            }

            // log functions not important
            override fun onStopPrinterDiscovery() {
                Log.d("myprinter", "MyPrintService#onStopPrinterDiscovery() called")
            }
            override fun onValidatePrinters(printerIds: List<PrinterId>) {
                Log.d(
                    "myprinter",
                    "MyPrintService#onValidatePrinters(printerIds: $printerIds) called"
                )
            }
            override fun onStartPrinterStateTracking(printerId: PrinterId) {
                Log.d(
                    "myprinter",
                    "MyPrintService#onStartPrinterStateTracking(printerId: $printerId) called"
                )
            }

            override fun onStopPrinterStateTracking(printerId: PrinterId) {
                Log.d(
                    "myprinter",
                    "MyPrintService#onStopPrinterStateTracking(printerId: $printerId) called"
                )
            }
            override fun onDestroy() {
                Log.d("myprinter", "MyPrintService#onDestroy() called")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPrintJobQueued(printJob: PrintJob) {
        Log.d("myprinter", "queued: " + printJob.id.toString())
        printJob.start()
        val document = printJob.document
        val `in` = FileInputStream(document.data!!.fileDescriptor)
        try {
            val buffer = ByteArray(4)
            `in`.read(buffer)
            Log.d("myprinter", "first " + buffer.size + "bytes of content: " + toString(buffer))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d("myprinter", "", e)
        } finally {
            try {
                `in`.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                assert(true)
            }
        }
        printJob.complete()
    }

    override fun onRequestCancelPrintJob(printJob: PrintJob) {
        Log.d("myprinter", "canceled: " + printJob.id.toString())
        printJob.cancel()
    }

    companion object {
        private fun toString(bytes: ByteArray): String {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            for (b in bytes) {
                sb.append(b.toString()).append(',')
            }
            if (sb.isNotEmpty()) {
                sb.setLength(sb.length - 1)
            }
            return sb.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MyPrintAdapter(private val data: File) : PrintDocumentAdapter() {
    override fun onLayout(
        oldAttributes: PrintAttributes?,
        newAttributes: PrintAttributes?,
        cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal?,
        callback: LayoutResultCallback?,
        extras: Bundle?
    ) {
        if (cancellationSignal?.isCanceled == true) {
            callback?.onLayoutCancelled()
            return
        }
        val printInfo = newAttributes?.let {
            PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("My Document")
                .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
         .build()
        }

        // Check if the "EXTRA_PRINT_PREVIEW" flag is set in the extras bundle
        extras?.getBoolean(EXTRA_PRINT_PREVIEW, false) ?: false

        callback?.onLayoutFinished(printInfo, false)
    }

    override fun onWrite(
        pages: Array<out PageRange>?,
        parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor?,
        cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal?,
        callback: WriteResultCallback?
    ) {
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(data)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor)

        val buf = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytesRead: Int

        try {
            while (inputStream.read(buf).also { bytesRead = it } > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead)
            }
            callback?.onWriteFinished(arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            callback?.onWriteFailed(e.message)
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close()
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```